# What's the difference between DQMJ2 and DQMJ2 Professional?

Tags: version-differences, dragon-quest-monsters-joker-2

*Dragon Quest Monsters: Joker 2* is a game I have beaten and played many a time. So much, that it would be nearly impossible for me to play it again in the near future because I would get bored easily. However, I stumbled across something about DQMJ2 I had never seen before. I found out about DQMJ2 Professional. What is this? Is it the same as DQMJ2's story line? And does it have more content, like more monsters and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Professional version is a sort of expanded version of the original DQM:J2. There are new monsters and maps. The story however is the same.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Quest_Monsters:_Joker_2):

> Square Enix released Joker 2 Professional, an expanded version of the game, on March 31, 2011. Professional features over 100 new monsters, as well as new regions and abilities, but the same story. Players are able to import their old monsters from the original game.

And [Wikia](http://dragonquest.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Quest_Monsters:_Joker_2_Professional):

> Hundreds of new monsters have been announced for the upcoming "Final Mix" of DQM:J2, some of these include: [list, not very helpfull here I think]

Also from [Wikia](http://dragonquest.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Quest_Monsters:_Joker_2_Professional), but about the end-game (spoiler-ish):

> Also a sword wielding monster that seems to resemble Akira Toriyama's "Super saiyan" and "Oozaru" creations combined. But it appears that it could possibly be a monster form of the main character Alexandre. A "final-final" boss has been added to the new map made in Pro and is concluded to be more difficult than Malevolynx and Rigor Mortex.